# Azure function is not logging custom events, dependencies to app insights

Tags: c#, azure-functions, azure-application-insights, telemetry, ilogger

We have an `Azure Function V3` developed in `C#`. We tried to log some `custom events, dependencies`, etc to `Azure Application Insights`. We are not able to log in app insights using `TelemetryClient`. The code runs fine without any errors. Also, could see the `instrumentation key` retrieved from the config file. However `Ilogger` logs can be found in the app insights traces table. Please find below the code that we used,

```cs
public class CommunityCreate
{
    private readonly TelemetryClient telemetryClient;
    public CommunityCreate(TelemetryConfiguration telemetryConfiguration)
    {
        this.telemetryClient = new TelemetryClient(telemetryConfiguration);
    }

    [FunctionName("Function1")]
    [return: ServiceBus("sample", Connection = "ServiceBusProducerConnection")]
    public async Task<string> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = "Account/{id:int?}")] HttpRequest req, string id, ILogger log)
    {
        //log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
        DateTime start = DateTime.UtcNow;

        string name = req.Query["name"];

        string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
        dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
        name = name ?? data?.name;

        var evt = new EventTelemetry("Function called");
        evt.Context.User.Id = name;
        this.telemetryClient.TrackEvent(evt);

        // Generate a custom metric, in this case let's use ContentLength.
        this.telemetryClient.GetMetric("contentLength").TrackValue(req.ContentLength);

        // Log a custom dependency in the dependencies table.
        var dependency = new DependencyTelemetry
        {
            Name = "GET api/planets/1/",
            Target = "swapi.co",
            Data = "https://swapi.co/api/planets/1/",
            Timestamp = start,
            Duration = DateTime.UtcNow - start,
            Success = true
        };
        
        dependency.Context.User.Id = name;
        this.telemetryClient.TrackDependency(dependency);

        telemetryClient.TrackEvent("Ack123 Received");
        telemetryClient.TrackMetric("Test Metric", DateTime.Now.Millisecond);

        return name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make sure you're using the correct packages as below:

[Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Logging.ApplicationInsights, version 3.0.18](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Logging.ApplicationInsights/3.0.18/)

and

update the package `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions` the latest version 3.0.9.

If you're running the project locally, please add the `APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY` in `local.settings.json`, like below:

```
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "xxxx",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
    "APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY": "xxx"
  }
}
```

Or if you're running it on azure portal, please configure the Application insights with azure function.

Then I tested your code, the custom events or dependency are correctly logged into Application insights. Here is the screenshot:

[image]

If you still have the issue, please let me know(and please also provide more details).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. Everything else is fine, but I was using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights package instead of Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Logging.ApplicationInsights. But i dont see TelemetryClient object in Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Logging.ApplicationInsights library. Am i missing something?

Comment: @Raj, the `TelemetryClient` is in the `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights` package. But when you install the package `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Logging.ApplicationInsights`, the package `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights` will be automatically installed as well. Because the 2 packages have dependency relationship. So you can also use `TelemetryClient`.

Comment: I have all these packages. But still i could not see logs in app insights.

Comment: @Raj, where are you running the project? in azure or locally?

Comment: @Raj, I suggest that you can test it locally as per the steps in my answer. And during test, please take a look at the visual studio output window, to see if there are any telemetry data being sent.

Comment: i tried both locally and Azure. In local also, i could not see telemetry logs in Visual Studio output window

Comment: @Raj do you mind showing your local.settings.json file?

Comment: {
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
    "ServiceBusConsumerConnection": "url value",
    "ServiceBusProducerConnection": "url value",
    "APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY": "xcxxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxx",
    "AzureWebJobsSecretStorageType": "files"
  }

Comment: @Raj, it seems ok to me. And I created a simple http-triggered function(not exactly like yours), it works fine. You can download it and test it at your side. The link is [here](https://yy1.blob.core.windows.net/test3/FunctionApp18.zip). And if the issue still occurs, I will continue working on it tomorrow.